# I need help setting firebase to flutter project

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart

I'm trying to add firebase to my existing flutter project but when I add the dependencies it shows this error message:

```
Running "flutter pub get" in green_app...                       
Because no versions of google_fonts match >2.3.1 <3.0.0 and google_fonts 2.3.1 depends on http ^0.13.0, google_fonts ^2.3.1 requires http ^0.13.0.
And because http >=0.13.0 depends on http_parser ^4.0.0, google_fonts ^2.3.1 requires http_parser ^4.0.0.
And because firebase_auth >=0.20.1 <0.21.0-1.0.nullsafety.0 depends on firebase_auth_web ^0.3.3 which depends on http_parser ^3.1.3, google_fonts ^2.3.1 is incompatible with firebase_auth >=0.20.1 <0.21.0-1.0.nullsafety.0.
So, because green_app depends on both firebase_auth ^0.20.1 and google_fonts ^2.3.1, version solving failed.
pub get failed (1; So, because green_app depends on both firebase_auth ^0.20.1 and google_fonts ^2.3.1, version solving failed.)
```

and here is my pubspec.yaml

```
c:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  firebase_core: "^0.7.0"
  firebase_auth: "^0.20.1"
  cloud_firestore: "^0.16.0"
  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2
  flutter_svg: ^1.0.3
  google_fonts: ^2.3.1
```

Comment: Either you remove `google_fonts` and instead download the fonts you need and add them to `assets` so you can use them with the `fontFamily` attribute(which is easier), or you have to use a lower version of `firebase_auth` or `google_fonts` so both of them have the same version of `http_parser`.